# Performance metrics for a VHDL/Verilog RTL design

Tags: vhdl, hdl, optimization, rtl, performance

Correctness and performance is everything in programming. Verifying it for software is relatively easy because you can "just" run the program and see if it crashes and/or is  very slow. Verifying correctness for hardware is also relatively easy because you can run the design in a simulator, but verifying performance (gate count, f_max, energy usage, size in um^2, etc.) is tricky.

So my question is how you do it when you don't have access to the target hardware (e.g ASIC  or high-end FPGA)? What free tools are there that can give you (approximate?)  performance metrics for HDL designs?

Answer (score 2):

The vendor FPGA toolchains will do fairly exact performance analysis, giving the exact resource counts, f_max for each clock, energy usage and required cooling solution, all during compilation.

Timing analysis is partially required for synthesis anyway, to decide optimum placement, and once synthesis is complete, a separate verification pass is performed. It is entirely possible that timings and energy usage for different synthesis attempts vary quite a bit.

Comment: The problem is that I  don't have a vendor tool-chain for Stratix 10 FPGA. So what do I do instead?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist, you can get QuartusII from the Intel web site.